how to change favicon in Gradio python
I have a very basic code for Gradio chat interface, how can i change favicon in Gradio chat interface
import time
import gradio as gr

def slow_echo(message, history):
  for i in range(len(message)):
      time.sleep(0.3)
      yield "You typed: " + message[: i+1]

gr.ChatInterface(slow_echo).launch()


You have to just provide path to your favicon
import time
import gradio as gr

def slow_echo(message, history):
  for i in range(len(message)):
      time.sleep(0.3)
      yield "You typed: " + message[: i+1]

gr.ChatInterface(slow_echo).launch(favicon_path='fav.jpg')

